# on change event fires only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to update cart whenever product quantity is changed. but jquery code is stop working after first time updating cart items.

here is jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("input.qty").on('keyup change click',function(){ 
        $('input[name=update_cart]').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: The code with you provide should work. However you need to share more information. As of now I don't think we can help.

Comment: Please add more information, you full code or a (not) working jsfiddle.

Comment: try to change this line as follows `$('input[name=update_cart]').click();`

Comment: @markoffden ok, i tried .click()  but still same problem

Comment: Here is website link, http://vccc.asn.au/cart/

Comment: try putting the code outside the document.ready() block.

Comment: Uhh.. it works perfect on my side.

Comment: what browser do you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(document).on('keyup change click','input.qty', function() {
    $('input[name=update_cart]').trigger('click');
  });
});
```

let me know if you require further information.

Comment: Can you please try with following code

$(this).closest('form').submit();

instead of

$('input[name=update_cart]').trigger('click');

Answer (score 0):

Use the input event

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("input.qty").on('input',function(){ 
        $(this).closest('form').submit(); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working. See result of below code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var count = 0;
    $("input.qty").on('keyup change click',function(){ 
        $('input[name=update_cart]').trigger('click');
        count++;
    });
    $('input[name=update_cart]').click(function(e){
        $(this).val('Click called  '+count);
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<input class="qty" name="test"/>
<input  name="update_cart"/>
```